# <form action="javascript:alert(this);"> what is "this"?

Tags: javascript

When trying to debug what is being submitted, I wrote this.

```
<form action="javascript:alert(this);"
```

1. Is it possible to alert what is
   being submitted?
2. Here "this" denotes what?

I got object in alert box & unable to decide anything out of it. :-)

Comment: You can get more information with console.dir() in either Firebug (Firefox extension) or Web Inspector (Safari/Chrome developer tools).

Comment: Also, try doing "alert(this.innerHTML)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example `this` is the global `window` object. Try it yourself:

```
<form action="javascript:alert(typeof this.setTimeout);">
```

results in `"function"` (i.e. the global function). Or try:

```
<form action="javascript:alert(this.nodeType);">
```

results in `undefined` (i.e. it's *not* pointing to the form element)*.

The value of `"this"` inside an attribute will only ever be one of two things:

1. the global `window` object
2. the element itself

The only time `this` points to the element itself is when it is used inside an [intrinsic event attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) (the ones that are prefixed with `"on"`, eg `"onclick"`, `"onload"`, etc). These attributes are special: the browser re-scopes `this` to the element the event is firing on, and creates the `event` object (with that name) also available inside the attribute.

If the attribute is *not* one of the intrinsic events, `"this"` will be the global `window` object.

---

Footnotes:

* unless of course you happened to have a global var named `"nodeType"`

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="javascript:alert(this === window);">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

pops up "true" when you click "Submit". It's the window object. One possibly relevant reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener -- see the section under "The value of this within the handler".

Answer (score 0):

`this` when used in JavaScript in an HTML element's attribute is a reference of the element itself. So `this` in the context of your form is the *form* DOM object.

In other words, a rather handy use of the the keyword :)

Comment: Nope, the keyword `this` points to the element only for intrinsic event attributes (eg `"onfoo"`).